# How to get cellID in CTTelephonyNetworkInfo

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, iphone-privateapi

how can I get cellId value in CTTelephonyNetworkInfo? Below is my code that i tried, but it still doesn't working.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Cell ID Value : %@", [telephonyInfo cellID]);
```

Here is CTTelephonyNetworkInfo header that I used as references : 
https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h

I DID NOT PLAN TO SUBMIT THIS APP TO APPSTORE.
I'M BUILDING A NORMAL APP NOT JAILBREAK APP, BUT I WANT THIS VALUE USING PRIVATE API. 
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Your are aware that these no public API thus there is no 100% way of telling whether it will work or not in all iOS versions. Also you will not be able to submit to the AppStore with this code. It might be wise to add the jailbreak tag.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of it will not pass app store. I'm not building jailbreak app, I'm building a normal app but I want get those value using private api.

Answer (score 1):

If you work on a jailbreak phone ,maybe can use the below entitlement:

```
<key>com.apple.CommCenter.fine-grained</key>
<array>
    <string>spi</string>
</array>
```